# Spring Boot app freezes on startup using Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate

```
2021-05-30 17:35:18.765  INFO 9812 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...

2021-05-30 17:35:19.462  INFO 9812 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.

2021-05-30 17:35:19.519  INFO 9812 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
```

After that, it just hangs indefinitely. No more debug messages are outputted, and nothing happens. I've let it sit there for hours, but nothing.
I have no idea why it's just freezing.

[log of freezing and after 30 minutes it's working (click on this link for view image)   [image for log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGSRG.jpg)

check this image after freezing it's working fine but after 30 minutes.
I don't why it takes 30 or 40 minutes to launch.

Comment: Attach a debugger or a profiler and inspect.

Answer (score 1):

try disabling hibernate schemavalidation i.e. set spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell like this what could be the possible reason.
You can try below things :

- First, check DB is up and you are able to connect to DB externally?
- If yes, Try dropping and recreating schema.
- Take thread dumps to see what exactly thread is doing - it will give hints for the direction to check things.
- Set hibernate's `show sql` property to `true`. You might see the sql, if any , causing the issue.
- Set the debug in Spring Beans which initialises the DB and check where is exactly failing.

Comment: I am trying to add all hibernate's show SQL property but don't view after initializing dialect any log. please check the image.